# Split strings in multiple columns into rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently working on a Google Sheet and I want to split a few columns that have strings into rows across the entire worksheet.

I used a script found on this platform which was helpful but the data came out with some errors. Wonder if someone could help me solve this.

I am very new to javascript.

**Original Data** looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBmim.png)

I would like it to look like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkTV9.png)

However, it turns out like this, where it duplicates some of the texts. I've highlighted it in red.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htm7Y.png)

Here's the script that I used and the link to a [sample worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qaLTduNXf-CalpEiZufwdHPPO2mzmYuri6GeACpF_n0/edit?usp=sharing).

```js
function result(range) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i in range) {
    var celLen = 1;
    var c1 = range[i].map(function(e, i){
      var cell = e.toString().split("\n"); // Modified
      var len = cell.length;
      if (len == 1) {
        return cell[0];
      } else if (len > 1) {
        celLen = celLen > len ? celLen : len;
        var t2 = [];
        for (var k=0; k<cell.length; k++) {
          t2.push(cell[k]);
        }
        return t2;
      }
    });
    var c2 = c1.map(function(e, i){
      var r = [];
      if (!Array.isArray(e)) {
        for (var k=0; k<celLen; k++) {
          r.push(e);
        }
      } else {
        for (var k in e) {
          r.push(e[k]);
        }
        if (e.length < celLen) {
          for (var m=0; m<celLen - e.length; m++) {
            r.push("");
          }
        }
      }
      return r;
    });
    var c3 = c2[0].map(function(e, i){return c2.map(function(f, j){return c2[j][i]})});
    Array.prototype.push.apply(output, c3);
  }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: When I tested your script, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your sample current output situation from your sample input situation. I apologize for this. So can I ask you about the detailed flow for replicating your issue? And, how do you run your script? Can you explain the detail of it using your sample input image?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you for your fast response. Here's a link to show you what I meant. I'd highlighted the errors in the 'Result' sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qaLTduNXf-CalpEiZufwdHPPO2mzmYuri6GeACpF_n0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Pls share a spreadsheet. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: This can be done by a formula, but I don't understand the relation between input and ouput!

Comment: Hi @MikeSteelson, thanks for the advice. I'm new here. Will edit the question and add in the link.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. From your sample Spreadsheet, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script, in your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const result = range =>
  range.flatMap(([a, ...v]) => {
    const { vv, len } = v.reduce((o, c) => {
      const t = c.split(",");
      o.vv.push(t);
      o.len = o.len < t.length ? t.length : o.len;
      return o;
    }, { vv: [], len: 0 });
    const temp = vv.map(e => e.concat(Array(len - e.length).fill("")));
    return temp[0].map((_, c) => [a, ...temp.map(r => r[c])]);
  });
```

#### Result:

When this script is used by putting a formula of `=RESULT(Data!A:E)`, the following result is obtained.

##### From:

[image]

##### To:

[image]

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, it works! Thank you so much! Is there a way I can expand this so that it applies to more than just 4 columns? I noticed I can go all the way up to column G but not beyond.

Comment: Yes, I can do that but how do I close it? I've tried looking for a 'close question' tab.